# compilation error g++ 5.2 Windows 10 out of ideas

Tags: compiler-errors, g++

i have these compilation errors and i really can't see what's wrong with my code, help me please

g++ complains mostly about some line not using the '->' operator but i'm using it so this error seems strange to me

```
g++ tests/client.cpp src/jsonrpc/transport/PipeClient.cpp -o client --std=c++11 -I ./include -lstdc++ -lboost_thread-mgw52-mt-1_59 -lboost_system-mgw52-mt-1_59 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600
include/jsonrpc/Client.h: In instantiation of 'bool jsonrpc::Client<ServerSocketType, ClientSocketType>::connect(std::__cxx11::string) [with ServerSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeServer; ClientSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeClient; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]':
tests/client.cpp:13:42:   required from here
include/jsonrpc/Client.h:29:48: error: request for member 'connect' in '((jsonrpc::Client<jsonrpc::PipeServer, jsonrpc::PipeClient>*)this)->jsonrpc::Client<jsonrpc::PipeServer, jsonrpc::PipeClient>::m_socket', which is of pointer type 'jsonrpc::PipeClient*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
include/jsonrpc/Client.h: In instantiation of 'bool jsonrpc::Client<ServerSocketType, ClientSocketType>::sendRequest(jsonrpc::Request*) [with ServerSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeServer; ClientSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeClient]':
tests/client.cpp:19:32:   required from here
include/jsonrpc/Client.h:52:34: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::__cxx11::string& {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'
include/jsonrpc/Client.h:85:18: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'bool jsonrpc::Client<ServerSocketType, ClientSocketType>::sendPacket(std::__cxx11::string&) [with ServerSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeServer; ClientSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeClient; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
                         packet.append(buffer, bytesRead);
                  ^
include/jsonrpc/Client.h: In instantiation of 'void jsonrpc::Client<ServerSocketType, ClientSocketType>::disconnect() [with ServerSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeServer; ClientSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeClient]':
include/jsonrpc/Client.h:24:27:   required from 'jsonrpc::Client<ServerSocketType, ClientSocketType>::~Client() [with ServerSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeServer; ClientSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeClient]'
tests/client.cpp:11:36:   required from here
include/jsonrpc/Client.h:34:17: error: request for member 'disconnect' in '((jsonrpc::Client<jsonrpc::PipeServer, jsonrpc::PipeClient>*)this)->jsonrpc::Client<jsonrpc::PipeServer, jsonrpc::PipeClient>::m_socket', which is of pointer type 'jsonrpc::PipeClient*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
In file included from ./include/jsonrpc/Request.h:4:0,
                 from include/jsonrpc/Client.h:6:
./include/jsonrpc/Message.h: In instantiation of 'static std::__cxx11::string jsonrpc::Message::toJson(const std::vector<MessageType*>&) [with MessageType = jsonrpc::Request; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]':
include/jsonrpc/Client.h:52:59:   required from 'bool jsonrpc::Client<ServerSocketType, ClientSocketType>::sendRequest(jsonrpc::Request*) [with ServerSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeServer; ClientSocketType = jsonrpc::PipeClient]'
tests/client.cpp:19:32:   required from here
./include/jsonrpc/Message.h:57:21: error: no matching function for call to 'rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<> >::Swap(jsonrpc::Request* const&)'
In file included from ./include/jsonrpc/Message.h:4:0,
                 from ./include/jsonrpc/Request.h:4,
                 from include/jsonrpc/Client.h:6:
D:/usr/msys2/mingw64/include/rapidjson/document.h:655:19: note: candidate: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>& rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::Swap(rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>&) [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>]
     GenericValue& Swap(GenericValue& other) RAPIDJSON_NOEXCEPT {
                   ^
D:/usr/msys2/mingw64/include/rapidjson/document.h:655:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const value_type {aka jsonrpc::Request* const}' to 'rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >&'
```

tests/client.cpp

```
#include "jsonrpc/Client.h"
#include "jsonrpc/transport/PipeServer.h"
#include "jsonrpc/transport/PipeClient.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace jsonrpc;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Client<PipeServer, PipeClient> client;

    client.connect("\\\\.\\pipe\\jsonrpc");

    typedef Request::ValueType Value;

    Request request(Value("_1").Move(), Value("test").Move(), Value(rapidjson::kArrayType).Move());

    client.sendRequest(&request);

    std::vector<Response *> responses;
    client.recvResponses(responses);

    std::cout << responses[0]->toJson() << std::endl;
}
```

jsonrpc/Client.h

```
#ifndef JSONRPC_CLIENT_H
#define JSONRPC_CLIENT_H

#include "jsonrpc/base.h"
#include "jsonrpc/Server.h"
#include "jsonrpc/Request.h"
#include "jsonrpc/Response.h"

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

namespace jsonrpc
{
    template <typename ServerSocketType, typename ClientSocketType>
    class Server;

    template <typename ServerSocketType, typename ClientSocketType>
    class Client
    {
        typedef Server<ServerSocketType, ClientSocketType> ServerType;
        typedef Client<ServerSocketType, ClientSocketType> ClientType;

        friend ServerType;

        public:
            Client() : m_socket(new ClientSocketType()), m_server(NULL) {}

            ~Client()
            {
                disconnect();
            }

            bool connect(const std::string & address)
            {
                return m_socket->connect(address);
            }

            void disconnect()
            {
                m_socket->disconnect();
            }

            bool recvResponses(std::vector<Response *> & responses)
            {
                std::string packet;

                if (!this->recvPacket(packet)) {
                    return false;
                }

                responses = Response::parseJson<Response>(packet);

                return true;
            }

            bool sendRequest(Request * request)
            {
                return sendRequests(std::vector<Request *>(1, request));
            }

            bool sendRequests(std::vector<Request *> & requests)
            {
                std::string packet = Request::toJson<Request>(requests);
                return sendPacket(packet);
            }

        private:
            ClientSocketType * m_socket;
            ServerType * m_server;

            Client(ClientSocketType * socket, ServerType * server) : m_socket(socket), m_server(server) {}

            bool recvPacket(std::string & packet)
            {
                char * buffer = new char[JSONRPC_READ_BUFFER_LENGTH];

                packet.empty();

                do {
                    ssize_t bytesRead = m_socket->read(buffer, JSONRPC_READ_BUFFER_LENGTH);

                    if (bytesRead > 0) {
                        packet.append(buffer, bytesRead);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } while (packet[packet.length() - 1] != '\n');

                return packet.size() > 0;
            }

            bool sendPacket(std::string & packet)
            {
                packet += "\n";

                size_t length = packet.length();
                size_t offset = 0;

                while (offset < length) {
                    ssize_t bytesWritten = m_socket->write(packet.c_str() + offset, std::min<size_t>(JSONRPC_WRITE_BUFFER_LENGTH, length - offset));

                    if (bytesWritten > 0) {
                        offset += bytesWritten;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                m_socket->flush();
            }

            void start()
            {
                boost::thread thread(boost::bind(ClientType::run, this));
            }

            void run()
            {
                std::string packet;

                while (recvPacket(packet)) {
                    handlePacket(packet);
                }
            }

            void handlePacket(std::string packet)
            {
                typedef Request::ValueType Value;

                std::vector<Request *> requests = Request::parseJson<Request>(packet);
                std::vector<Response *> responses;

                for (Request * request : requests) {
                    Response * response;

                    if (request->IsNull()) {
                        response = new Response(Value().Move(), Value(-32700).Move(), Value("Parse error").Move());
                    } else if (request->isValid()) {
                        response = m_server->handleRequest(request);
                    } else if (request->hasValidId()) {
                        response = new Response(Value(request->getId(), request->GetAllocator).Move(), Value(-32600).Move(), Value("Invalid request").Move());
                    } else {
                        response = new Response(Value().Move(), Value(-32600).Move(), Value("Invalid request").Move());
                    }

                    delete request;
                    responses.push_back(response);
                }

                sendPacket(Response::toJson<Response>(responses).c_str());
            }
    };
}

#endif // JSONRPC_CLIENT_H
```

jsonrpc/Message.h

```
#ifndef JSONRPC_MESSAGE_H
#define JSONRPC_MESSAGE_H

#include <vector>

#include <rapidjson/document.h>
#include <rapidjson/writer.h>

namespace jsonrpc
{
    class Message : public rapidjson::Document
    {
        typedef rapidjson::StringBuffer StringBuffer;
        typedef rapidjson::Writer<StringBuffer> StringWriter;

        public:
            const ValueType & getId() const
            {
                return operator[]("id");
            }

            const Ch * toJson()
            {
                StringBuffer buffer;
                StringWriter writer(buffer);

                Accept(writer);

                return buffer.GetString();
            }

            template <typename MessageType>
            static std::vector<MessageType *> parseJson(const std::string & json)
            {
                rapidjson::Document document;
                document.Parse(json.c_str());

                std::vector<MessageType *> messages;

                if (document.IsArray()) {
                    for (rapidjson::SizeType i = 0; i < document.Size(); ++i) {
                        messages.push_back(new MessageType(document[i]));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    messages.push_back(new MessageType(document));
                } 

                return messages;
            }

            template <typename MessageType>
            static std::string toJson(std::vector<MessageType *> & messages)
            {
                rapidjson::Document document;
                size_t nbMessages = messages.size();

                if (nbMessages == 1) {
                    document.Swap(messages[0]->Move());
                }
                else if (nbMessages > 1) {
                    document.SetArray();

                    for (MessageType * message : messages) {
                        document.PushBack(*message, document.GetAllocator());
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return "";
                }

                StringBuffer buffer;
                StringWriter writer(buffer);

                document.Accept(writer);

                return buffer.GetString();
            }
    };
}

#endif // JSONRPC_MESSAGE_H
```